# Playwright tests - using variable from .env file

Tags: typescript, playwright, dotenv, playwright-test

I've got Playwright test written using TypeScript and I would like to use variables from .env in my test file,  how can I do that?

Answer (score 9):

You can put `require('dotenv').config()` inside your `playwright.config.ts` and then it will work, see here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Max Schmitt's answer, here's 3 other ways to do it:

#### dotenv-cli

Add [dotenv-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-cli) to your dev dependencies then use it: `dotenv playwright test` (or `npx dotenv playwright test` if you're running this command outside of a package.json script).

#### require + NODE_OPTIONS

Use the `--require` Node.js option and `NODE_OPTIONS` to set it: `NODE_OPTIONS=--require=dotenv/config playwright test`.

#### require + npx

Use the `--require` Node.js option and npx to set it: `npx --node-options=--require=dotenv/config playwright test` (if you're using an old version of npx, you might need to replace `--node-options` by `--node-arg`)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how I do it:

```js
// playwright.config.ts 

import { PlaywrightTestConfig } from '@playwright/test';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'){
  require('dotenv').config({path: '.env'});
}

const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [env-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd):

```js
// playwright.config.ts
import "dotenv/config";

import { defineConfig, devices } from "@playwright/test";
...
```

```json
// package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "env-cmd -f .env.development --no-override playwright test",
    "test:staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging --no-override playwright test",
    "test:production": "env-cmd -f .env.production --no-override playwright test"
  },
}
```

**In addition:**
With `env-cmd`, the environment variables can be set in any format like `.js` or `.json`. Advanced usage details are [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd#-advanced-usage).

Add `.env-cmdrc` in the root folder. I preferred to use it for test commands only.

```
{
  "development": {
    "BASE_URL": "DEV_URL"
  },
  "staging": {
    "BASE_URL": "STAGING_URL"
  },
  "production": {
    "BASE_URL": "PROD_URL"
  }
}
```

In `package.json`:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "env-cmd --environments development --no-override playwright test",
    "test:staging": "env-cmd --environments staging --no-override playwright test",
    "test:production": "env-cmd --environments production --no-override playwright test"
  },
}
```